# Magento doesn't read default value

Tags: magento-1.9, database, configuration

Magento does not get the information from the default value for several config settings. We recently added a new website and store, maybe it's related somehow.

For example the timezone is not retrieved correctly. We set Europe/Berlin as default value, but our German store does not read from it. It returns null.

Here our configuration for default:
[image: Default]

And here for our German website
[image: German]:

The configurations in our database seem to be correct as well.
The entries for *general/locale/timezone* in *core_config_data*:

7435websites12general/locale/timezoneEurope/Berlin
3909websites10general/locale/timezoneAtlantic/Reykjavik
3407websites8general/locale/timezoneEurope/Berlin
7436websites1general/locale/timezoneEurope/Berlin
543default0general/locale/timezoneEurope/Berlin

However when I run the following code to retrieve the data, it returns NULLwhile I expected Europe/Berlin:

```
var_dump(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone', 3));
```

Comment: Can you share the locale options tab for your German Website? Also what's the scope of "Germany" is it a Website a Store or a Storeview ?

Comment: The locale tab for the german website is in the 2nd sceenshot of the question. And the score is website.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause after debugging how Mangento builds it's configuration. A plugin created entries in the core_config_data table for a store, but put the scope to default.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly the issue was? I am running into a similar problem but can't exactly figure out how you solved yours.

Comment: As you can see in above's screenshot. The scope is et to default, while the score_id is referring to a store_id.
So check the core_config_data table if scores and scope_id's are matching correctly.